# Where to find a summary for Q functions?

Tags: documentation

Is there a summary for all Function like
NumberQ, LetterQ and so forth?

```
data=123;
IntegerQ[data]

True
```

Answer (score 12):

Do you mean a list of functions ending in Q?

```
?*Q
```

[image: shot]

Comment: (+1) or  ?*`*Q to get all 1243 functions.

Comment: There is an example like this in the documentation page on Information. Typing "?" in help is useless :( (it does not bring you to Information). Also the syntax is so special that you cannot do something like Hold[?*Q]//FullForm to find out what function is being used. So I figured I'd post this.

Comment: Of course, not all of these are querying functions. `EllipticNomeQ[]`, `LegendreQ[]`, and `MarcumQ[]` are examples that spring to mind.